# How to set properties of a JButton ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jbutton

I have a `JButton` `ArrayList`. The code below does not work. How can I access a specific button from the array list and set the size, location and other properties and also add it to the applet?

```
ArrayList<String> cdTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<JButton> btnCDS = new ArrayList<JButton>();
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Initialize")) {
            cdTitles.add("Original Order");
            cdTitles.add("Metric - Fantasies");
            cdTitles.add("Beatles - Abby Road");
            cdTitles.add("Pearl Jam - Ten");
            cdTitles.add("Doors - Alive");
            cdTitles.add("The Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter");

            for(int i = 0; i < cdTitles.size(); i++) {
                String buttonName = "btn" + i;
                System.out.println(buttonName);
                btnCDS.add(new JButton(buttonName));
                break;
            }
            btnCDS.get(0).setText(cdTitles.get(0));
            btnCDS.get(0).setLocation(100, 145);
            btnCDS.get(0).setSize(520, 25);
            add(btnCDS.get(0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 3) *"set the size, location"* The size of a button is suggested by the text and icon it contains, and the layout it is added to. The location of a button is determined by the layout. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout ..

Comment: .. of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

provided that this is executing in a Applet sub-class,
this works for me:

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    // all your code between:
    // cdTitles.add("Original Order");
    // AND
    // add(btnCDS.get(0));

    // Watch out for dead code in the for loop.
}
```